# Crosstabs Using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns of Age_group(10 to 20,20 to 30,30 to 40,40 to 50) 60), Tenure(1:5) and Response(True or False )how to create a table which gives me count of true for each group and tenure.

For eg

```
       1 2 3 4 5 
10-20  
20-30  Count of True's
30-40  
40-50
```

Comment: I would ask the same question to Google first, just read the 4-5 results from the first page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(age = sample(seq(10,50,5),100, replace = T), 
             tenure = sample(1:5, 100, replace = T), 
             response = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T))

 head(df)

age tenure response
1  10      5        0
2  50      4        0
3  30      5        0
4  10      4        0
5  25      5        0
6  35      1        0

dcast(df, age ~ tenure,sum, value.var = 'response')


  age 1 2 3 4 5
1  10 0 0 2 1 1
2  15 1 2 3 0 0
3  20 3 0 0 0 0
4  25 0 1 1 3 0
5  30 2 2 0 2 2
6  35 0 1 2 0 5
7  40 2 0 2 0 0
8  45 0 0 3 1 0
9  50 1 0 0 2 0
```

Comment: Thanks. .Can we do it without converting the response variable to 1,0.

Comment: The function sum in R base  coerces logical variables (TRUE, FALSE) to numeric and performs the calculation, so yes, we can.